# Lightning icon rendering issue

Tags: lightning

Whenever I switch from Classic to Lightning environment my Production org doesn't render the icons of the object names instead it renders the alternative text which makes the UI look terrible and distorted is there any way I can render the object icons instead of alternative text?

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is because of the browser caching.Try to clear your browser cache and the image of the Object Icons will render instead of alternative text.